# ¿Como hacer para que un bucle While cese de ejecutarse?

Tags: c#, bucles, while

```
int tiempo, monto;
Console.WriteLine("¿Desea alquilar una bicicleta?");
string bicicleta = Console.ReadLine();

while(bicicleta != "no")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos a Colonial Road");
    Console.WriteLine("Una hora cuesta 300 pesos ");

    Console.WriteLine("¿Cuando tiempo deseas montar?");
    tiempo = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    monto = tiempo * 300;

    Console.WriteLine($"El monto total a pagar es:{monto}");

    Console.WriteLine("Su tiempo ha finalizado ¿desea una hora mas?");
    string final = Console.ReadLine();
}
Console.WriteLine("Gracias por preferirnos, vuelva pronto...");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Básicamente el problemas está en que cuando el programa pregunta "desea una hora mas" el bucle se repite aunque la respuesta haya sido "no" y en verdad no entiendo por qué razón sucede eso si la pregunta está dentro del bucle y la condición vendría a ser "true" cuando el usuario responde "no" lo que quiero es que se rompa si el usuario respondió "no" en ese momento.
Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: Asignas el valor en `final` pero estás preguntando si `bicicleta != "no"`, tendrías que asignar el valor a `bicicleta` y así finaliza.

Comment: El condicional está sobre la variable `bicicleta`, ¿porqué crees que almacenar el valor en otra variable diferente hará que pare el bucle?

Comment: necesitas cambiar esto: `string final = Console.ReadLine();` por esto: `bicicleta = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todos, el problema era precisamente eso: en vez de guardarlo en la variable "bicicleta" cree una nueva y por eso el bucle se repetía, gracias a todos por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

solo tienes que cambiar tu variable final por la que ya declaraste: bicicleta, así:

```
 int tiempo, monto;
        Console.WriteLine("¿Desea alquilar una bicicleta?");
        string bicicleta = Console.ReadLine();

        while (bicicleta != "no")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenidos a Colonial Road");

            Console.WriteLine("Una hora cuesta 300 pesos ");

            Console.WriteLine("¿Cuando tiempo deseas montar?");
            tiempo = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            monto = tiempo * 300;

            Console.WriteLine($"El monto total a pagar es:{monto}");

            Console.WriteLine("Su tiempo ha finalizado ¿desea una hora mas?");
            bicicleta = Console.ReadLine();

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Gracias por preferirnos, vuelva pronto...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el bucle, este va a realizarse siempre que el valor de la variable `bicicleta` sea diferente a "no"  (`bicicleta != "no"`), tendrías que asignar el valor a `bicicleta` de "no" y de esta forma finalizará el bucle.

```
while (bicicleta != "no")
        {
           ...
           ... 
           ...
           ...
           ...
        }
```

Para realizar esto debe obtener el valor de bicicleta dentro del bucle:

```
    while(bicicleta != "no")
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        Console.WriteLine("Su tiempo ha finalizado ¿desea una hora mas?");      
        //string final = Console.ReadLine();
        bicicleta = Console.ReadLine();
  
    }
```